# How to allow access on 'repair.order' for portal users: Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, security, odoo

I want to add access for portal users to see `repair.order` model in website.
So, I added these rules :

//  in CSV file

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_repair_order_portal,Repair order portal,repair.model_repair_order,base.group_portal,1,1,1,1
access_repair_line_portal,Repair portal,repair.model_repair_line,base.group_portal,1,1,1,1
```

//  in xml file

```
  <record id="repair_rule_portal" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Portal Repair Orders</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="repair.model_repair_order"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_portal'))]"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    </record>

    <record id="repair_line_rule_portal" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Portal Repair Orders Line</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="repair.model_repair_line"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_portal'))]"/>
    </record>
```

But always portal users haven't access, only Internal users have access to see repairs.

What's's wrong please?
Thanks.

Comment: What does Odoo tell you (log) when trying to access a repair order with a portal user?